# When using gradle with maven-publish, I get Cannot find wagon which supports the requested protocol: scp

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-publish

The error I get - ""
The property `uploadURL` is defined as `scp://user@host/data/apps/repo/m2`
Here are the relevant sections

```
configurations {
    deployerJars
}
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
//----------------------
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.0.2'
    }
}
//----------------------
apply plugin: 'maven'
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            //uploadURL is defined in a properties file. It is properly recognied
            //by gradle
            repository(url:upLoadURL) 
            uniqueVersion = false
        }

    }
}
//----------------------
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'


//----------------------
// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'maven central' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh:2.2"

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'


    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'


}
```

Comment: I forgot to put in the error. Here it is - "Unsupported Protocol: 'scp': Cannot find wagon which supports the requested protocol: scp"

Answer (score 2):

You created a configuration called `deployJars` that is unnecessary.

You are missing the `wagon` dependency for the `archives` `configuration`:

```
dependencies {
    archives "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-external:3.4.0"
}
```

So change `deployJars` to `archives`.

Then for `uploadArchives`, you need to specify the configuration:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.archives // <-- missing
            repository(url: "scpexe://yourhost/yourdir/") 
            uniqueVersion = false
        }

    }
}
```